# Как сверстать такую запись

Tags: html, css

[image: горизонтальный разделитель]

В итоге не совсем понятно как мне нарисовать в ячейке таблицы горизонтальный разделитель двух строчек.

Comment: Это может быть нижний боордер для текста..

Comment: используйте любой вариант с бордером - поставьте пустой div между текстами, нарисуйте отступы и рамку. Вариантов очень много - можно T.3 вставить в <p> и настроить нижний бордер.

Comment: Можно псевдоэлементом

Answer (score 3):

Можно, например, с помощью псевдоэлемента:

```css
.fraction-upper::after {
  width: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #ccc;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.cell {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">
  <p class="fraction-upper">Т. З</p>
  <p>2сп</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.some1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class="some1">
    some
  </div>
  <div class="some2">
    asd
  </div>
</div>
```